# How to change footer on change section with scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-native

I have created a new react-native app with tab option. There is one default footer shows when I run this app.

My question is I have created one component with four(4) sections, what I want to do is to change footer when scroll reaches a particular section.

[Here is full Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58947420/reset-or-change-bottomtabnavigator-text-and-route-dynamically-on-scroll-in-react)

Comment: Please add a question and a code example of what you already have

Comment: I have created a new react-native app with tab option. there is one default footer shows when I run this app. My question is I have created one component with four(4) sections, what I want to do is I want to change footer when scroll reaches a particular section. Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: @Julian: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58947420/reset-or-change-bottomtabnavigator-text-and-route-dynamically-on-scroll-in-react

Answer (score 0):

You should put a condition our scrolling.... our you Can make it by JQUERY like-
$(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.our-products').offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= $('.our-products').offset().top+$('.our-products').outerHeight() || $(this).scrollTop() >= $('.references').offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() <=

$('.references').offset().top+$('.references').outerHeight() || $(this).scrollTop() >= $('.our-team').offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= $('.our-team').offset().top+$('.our-team').outerHeight()|| $(this).scrollTop() >= $('.about-us').offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= $('.about-us').offset().top+$('.about-us').outerHeight() {

$(".logo").addClass('dark');
        }

```
    else{
        $(".logo").removeClass('dark');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: You can apply class and remove class by JQUERY...that will  help you

Comment: I want something like that - https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-f278197ae1a4.mp4 Thanks!